# Swift - Why it's possible to call the empty init of protocol-type OptionSet?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand Swift features by learning the standard library. But I found an unclear case with `OptionSet` protocol from Swift module.

Let's test the following code

```swift
let y: NSOrderedCollectionDifferenceCalculationOptions = .init()
```

Struct `NSOrderedCollectionDifferenceCalculationOptions` is declared in `Foundation` module and it inherits `OptionSet`. The code provided above is compilable, but why? If you click on `.init()`'s `Jump to defenition`, the source of `OptionSet` protocol will open. But why it's possible to call the init from inherited protocol type?

Thanks!

Comment: `.init()` was implemented as an extension of `OptionSet` providing default implementation

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/OptionSet.swift#L337

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's just a matter of understanding what a *protocol extension* is. A protocol extension has the ability not merely to declare a requirement (e.g. an adopter of this protocol must declare a certain function) but to *fulfill* that requirement (i.e. provide an *implementation* for that function).

Thus, when you read in the headers

```
extension OptionSet where Self.RawValue : FixedWidthInteger {
    /// Creates an empty option set.
    /// This initializer creates an option set with a raw value of zero.
    @inlinable public init()
}
```

...you are being told that OptionSet over an integer raw value acquires from this protocol extension an `init` implementation.